# How to effectively delete a specific component when using a v-for loop to render components

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Hi everyone and anyone,

I'm using a v-for loop in a vue.js 2 project to render some components,

there is basically 1 wrapper component that has the property count,

and for the value of count, it iterates and creates count number of child components, like so

```
// inventory.vue
template(
    v-for="(resource, index) in resourcesMutable" 
    )
    resource(
      v-if="resource && resource.description && typeof resource === 'object'"
      :resource="resource"
      :index="index"
      :key="resource._id"
      :options="resourceOptions"
      :style="{order: 2}"
      :neighbours="resourcesMutable"
      )
    resource(
      v-else-if="resource == undefined"
      :index="index"
      :key="index"
      :options="resourceOptions"
      :style="{order: 2}"
      :neighbours="resourcesMutable"
      )
```

Now the thing is that each of those child components, need's to have a function which deletes it from the resourcesMutable list which is used to render them.

What I've done is passed the index for each list item down to the child, then added a deleteResource function which splices the parent's resourcesMutable array to delete the user deleted the component.

Buuuut, this is having the unanticipated behaviour that the next sibling inherets the current data of the deleted component.

Here is how I delete the resource

```
// resource.vue
deleteResource(){
      this.neighboursMutable.splice(this.index, 1)
    },
```

and here is how I'm handling the key,

```
// resource.vue
computed: {
    resourceMutable: {
      get: function(){
        let value = this.resource || {
          description: "Start typing to create a new post, the first line or 200 characters will be used as the title unless otherwise chosen below",
          resource: 'new resource',
          uuid: this._uid
        }
        this.resource = value
        this.neighboursMutable[this.index] = value
        this.key = value.uuid
        // console.log(this.resourceMutable.uuid)
        return value
      }
    }
  },
```

now you might wonder why I set the key in the getter of a property of the component, well, that's because the parent component needs to support adding items to the list, so there's a button which simply appends undefined to the list being v-for'd,

because in my opinion, the parent component should not need to hold any of the default values for the rendered child component, the child should handle that,

but vue.js has this weird thing where when undefined is passed as a property, the property does not use it's default value, instead it means that you have to do this within a computed mutable variable, which is fine, but it also means that I can't just set the :key="resource.id" or whatever id,

what are you meant to use as a key for v-for'd data anyway, they really expect every iterated list to have id's on the list items??

so I set the key after the component is created

and I think this is actually working fine

when I add a few items to the list, I get an output that looks a little like this

```
item 0, this.key = 1329, this.index = 0
item 1, this.key = 1349, this.index = 1
item 2, this.key = 1379, this.index = 2 ( make this.options = ['woo'] )
item 3, this.key = 1419, this.index = 3
item 4, this.key = 1429, this.index = 4
```

But let's say I change the state of item 2, and make this.options = ['woo']

and then go

```
item 0, this.key = 1329, this.index = 0
item 1, this.key = 1349, this.index = 1
item 2, this.key = 1379, this.index = 2 ( click deleteResource )
item 3, this.key = 1419, this.index = 3
item 4, this.key = 1429, this.index = 4
```

then the new output looks like this

```
item 0, this.key = 1329, this.index = 0
item 1, this.key = 1349, this.index = 1
item 2, this.key = 1419, this.index = 2 ( but this component, with a different key, has this.options = ['woo'] )
item 3, this.key = 1429, this.index = 3
```

so what's going on there???

Oh and the options I'm talking about are even converted to 1 way binding via

```
this.optionsMutable = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.options))
```

so, I don't understand how a component with a ._uid of 1 value, can pass it's data state to another component with a different ._uid,

any ideas?

Comment: It strikes me as a profoundly bad idea to have a computed getter act as an initializer. Shouldn't that be in the `created` lifecycle hook?

Comment: @RoyJ I totally agree, I changed it so the list[index] is set in the created hook. It still doesn't answer how to use a key with an undefined list item.

I posted a more descriptive question on the vue.js forum 

https://forum.vuejs.org/t/what-to-use-as-a-key-to-enable-removing-of-components-rendered-with-a-v-for-loop-when-array-items-are-undefined/19352